# Heuristics to decide if to run an operation sychronous or asynchronous

Tags: apex, batch, future, asynchronous

Im our app we recently had to switch many operations from short running synchronous calls to asychronous Batch or future calls. It helps us overcome the many limits but also introduces many other problems (from a user and maintainance perspective).

Are there patterns, best practices or any other idea on how one decide/calculate before running an operation if it should be called synchronously or asynchronously?

If limits could be catched as exceptions I would just try to run it synchronously and retry asynch when this fails:

```
try {
  runSynchronously();
}
catch(LimitsException le) {
  runAsynchronously();
}
```

As this is not possible the code would more have to look like this:

```
if(willNotRunIntoLimits(allRelevantParams) {
  runSynchronously();
}
else {
  runAsynchronously();
}
```

Comment: Its difficult to perform the calculations if you have any form of rich data driving the processes, as that can flex when the governors are actually hit in a production environment. Such code is also hard to maintain as you continue to develop the code. My advise would be to move to Batch Apex (it gives a job ID to ease the user experience by presenting feedback to the user). If your users still want the option provide a custom setting and make it an implementation system wide choice that they buy into. Messaging to your users a more dynamic approach is also quite hard sometimes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to call a funtion that checks nearly all limits on every method call or loop iteration? If any resource is found to be close to a limit we gracyfully fail / rollback and restart in a batch/future manner... Would that work?!

Comment: You could see your code in such a way, but these checks themseleves would use up statements and also make your code very messy to read. In the end you do need some predictable way to message what your applications tolerances are to your customers thats the challenge. It depends how rich your data is, if it's simply, then maybe you can implement some kind of soft governor of your own base in the number of records at a high level. In testing you can use the Limits class to calibrarte if a certain number of records gives you enough head room, +/- some level of complexity.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot catch a LimitException in Salesforce once you hit it, your code just stops, and nothing else is done except for displaying the user the exception message.

You could however count your limits in your code, and see whether you'd hit the ones you are afraid of, throw an Exception yourself, catch that exception, and then start processing them asynchronously.

Salesforce has a whole lot of methods available for monitoring your limits:

[Read all about them in the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm)

Comment: I agree that the limits methods will probably be the best bet. [Apex Best Practice #7](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) is a great example of halting further processing based on the Limits in the current transaction. This could be altered to spawn @future calls instead of halting.